# Конкатенация char + символ + char C++

Tags: c++, строки, gcc

Есть такой код:

```
cout<<"Type path - ";
char path[NAME_MAX];
cin >> path;
DIR *check_dir;
check_dir = opendir(path);
if(check_dir){
    cout << "Какой файл создать? - ";
    char filename[NAME_MAX];
    cin>>filename;
    filename = path + "/" + filename; //эта строка помечается как ошибка.
    ifstream file;
    file.open(filename);
    if(file){
        cout<< "Exixts";
    }else{
        cout<<"Not exists";
    }
}else{
    cout << "Directiry not found";
}
return 0;
```

Нужно склеить:

```
char + "/" + char;
```

Есть ли решение?

Я пытаюсь донести до читающего проблему: Если я буду использовать string, то будет ошибка при открытии директории. По какой-то причине(мне не известной, opendir принимает только const char* как параметр)
Вот что получается при попытке использовать string:

```
cout<<"Type path - ";
string path;
cin >> path;
DIR *check_dir;
check_dir = opendir(path);//Эта строка становится ошибкой
if(check_dir){
    cout << "Какой файл создать? - ";
    string filename;
    cin>>filename;
    filename = path + "/" + filename; 
    ifstream file;
    file.open(filename);
    if(file){
        cout<< "Exixts";
    }else{
        cout<<"Not exists";
    }
}else{
    cout << "Directiry not found";
}
return 0;
```

`error: cannot convert ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘DIR* opendir(const char*)’`

Comment: ага, называется `string`.

Comment: к тому же мне что-то подсказывает, что склеить вам нужно не `char + "/" + char`, а `char * + "/" + char *`

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch в случае использования string ошибкой становится check_dir = opendir(path);

Comment: посмотрите мой ответ

Comment: Я честно говоря не понял зачем `opendir` и где `closedir`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы в строке:

```
filename = path + "/" + filename;
```

пытаетесь сложить два указателя на `char` и строковой литерал. Эта операция в принципе невозможна в данном виде. Для простой конкатенации, раз вы уж пишете на `с++`, следует использовать класс `string`. Тогда конкотенация будет выглядеть как то так:

```
std::string str = path;
str += "/";
str += filename;
```

Это если ваши строки (path, filename) оставить в той же форме (`char *`). Если же их тоже перевести в `string` то можно и так:

```
std::string str = path + '/' + filename.
```

PS Из `string` можно вернуть текст как указатель на массив `char`. Для этого нужно использовать метод `c_str()`

Comment: добавил в вопрос код и ошибку.

Comment: @МаксимДонец вы читать умеете? Я же внизу по-русски написал, что если вам нужен все-таки массив\указатель `char` то просто используйте метод `c_str()`. Что не понятного?

Answer (score 3):

- **C++**. Как уже отметили в комментариях, пользуйтесь `std::string` и забудьте об этой головной боли.
- **С**. Используйте `char * strcat( char * destptr, const char * srcptr );`. Эта функция добавляет информацию по указателю `srcptr` к информации по указателю `destptr`. Можно прибавить и строковый литерал типа `"/"`

Comment: добавил в вопрос код и ошибку

Comment: Так заведите отдельную переменную `char *`, откройте в нее директорию, а потом присвойте это значение вашей `string`-переменной

Comment: пробовал. не удается привести тип string к типу char*  и наоборот

Comment: пардоньте. все получилось. глупая невнимательность